# Letting the user define size of an array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

How can I let the user choose a number say n and then create an array with the size of n?

Can I just say `int a[]=malloc (n*sizeof(int))`?

Comment: I'd be careful letting users allocate an arry of any size. Unless they are trusted i.e you. A huge allocation could have stabilty issues

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do that. If the array size is small then you can use variable length array

```
/* Valid in C99 and later */
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int a[n];
```

This will allocate memory on stack. Other way is you can use dynamic memory allocation which will allocate memory on the heap

```
 int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: what do you consider a small array size?

Comment: @fbynite; Because generally stack has limited size and the memory for VLAs are allocated on stack.

Comment: yea, that's what I'm wondering about, the size. What's the size boundary where you say, this array might be in excess of X amount of bytes and it should be allocated on the heap instead?

Comment: Can't say much about it. It's OS job to allocate a fixed size memory for stack and it is completely platform specific. You can use `ulimit -s` or `ulimit -a` to check the stack size on your system. On my system `ulimit -s` shows `8192` kbytes.

Comment: VLAs are C since C99 only and optional since C11. In C++ they do not exist at all.

Comment: @alk; But question is tagged only C.

Comment: Yes, sure. My comment was not meant as criticism, but as addition only.

Comment: @alk; Didn't took it as criticism :) Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if u want to set the size of the array at run-time.

Then u should go for dynamic memory allocation(malloc/calloc).

```
int a[]=malloc (n*sizeof(int));//this not possible.
int *a =malloc (n*sizeof(int)); // this is possible.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is nearly correct:

```
int a[] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Using `malloc` is the correct way.
But you cannot assign the returned address to an array.

You must use a pointer variable instead:

```
int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways for allocating the memory to create an array where the size to the array is determined as input:

The first one is, 
allocating the memory for array in the 'stack' segment of memory where the size of array is taken as input ant then the array of that particular size is defined and granted memory accordingly.

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);            //scanning the size
int arr[n];                //declaring the array of that particular size here
```

The second one is,
allocating the required memory in the 'heap' segment of memory.It is the memory allocated during runtime (execution of the program) 
So,another way of declaring an array where size is defined by user is

```
int n,*arr;
scanf("%d",&n);
arr=malloc(n*sizeof(int));        //malloc function provides a contiguous space
```

or

```
arr=calloc(n,sizeof(int));      //calloc function is similar,initializes as 0
```

to use both these functions make sure to include stdlib.h.

Comment: No need to cast `void`-pointers in C. Just drop those `(int*)`.

Comment: VLAs are C since C99 only and optional since C11. In C++ they do not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Variable length arrays (VLAs) were added to C with C99, but made optional with C11. They are still widely supported, though. This is the simplest way to define an array with user-selected size at runtime.

Other than that VLAs may not be available on all platforms, they also may fail silently when there is an allocation failure. This is a disadvantage that `malloc()` avoids when used correctly.

You can't assign to an array in C, and instead you need to store the value returned by `malloc()` in a pointer. Note that `malloc()` returns `NULL` when there is an allocation failure, allowing code to check for failure and proceed accordingly. The actual allocation might look like this:

```
int *a_dyn = malloc(sizeof *a_dyn * arr_sz);
```

This is an idiomatic way of calling `malloc()`. Note that there is [no need to cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and note that the operand to `sizeof` is not an explicit type, but rather an expression involving `a_dyn`. The `sizeof` operator uses the *type* of the expression `*a_dyn`, which is in fact `int` (there is no dereference made). This is less error-prone and easier to maintain when types change during the life of a program than coding with explicit types. Also note that the `sizeof` expression comes before `arr_sz`. This is a good practice to follow: sometimes you might have a call like:

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * nrows * ncols);
```

Placing `sizeof` first forces the multiplication to be done using `size_t` values, helping to avoid overflow issues in the multiplication.

Don't forget to free any memory allocated with `malloc()` when it is no longer needed, avoiding memory leaks.

Whether you use a VLA or `malloc()`, you must validate user input before using it to avoid undefined behavior. Attempting to allocate an array of non-positive size leads to undefined behavior, and attempting to allocate too much memory will lead to an allocation failure.

Here is an example program that illustrates all of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_MAX  1024                 // some sensible maximum array size

int main(void)
{
    int arr_sz;
    int ret_val;
    /* validate user input */
    do {
        printf("Enter array size: ");
        ret_val = scanf("%d", &arr_sz);
    } while (ret_val != 1 || arr_sz < 1 || arr_sz > ARR_MAX);

    /* use a VLA */
    int a_vla[arr_sz];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++) {
        a_vla[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", a_vla[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    /* use malloc() */
    int *a_dyn = malloc(sizeof *a_dyn * arr_sz);
    if (a_dyn == NULL) {                                 // malloc failure?
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
    } else {                                             // malloc success
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++) {
            a_dyn[i] = i;
            printf("%d ", a_dyn[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    /* avoid memory leaks */
    free(a_dyn);

    return 0;
}
```